# When would nested Ifs be more useful than If-ands in Python logic?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, logic

When do we use nested Ifs and If-ands?

For example, if I wanted to write a code:

If (Income less than cut off):
If (Canadian Citizen?):
Receive social assistance

When would I use nested IF like above instead of If-and?
At first I assumed it was when we want to access the inner statement only when it evaluates to true but with IF-and you can still skip the inner statement if it evaluated to false.

Comment: It's typically a question of readability

Comment: You usually use nested `if` when there are multiple nested conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if cond_1 is True and cond_2 is True:
  do_this()
...
```

and

```
if cond_1 is True:
  if cond_2 is True:
    do_this()
  else:  # cond_2 is False but cond_1 is still True
    do_other()
...
```

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks for the example, I see the difference now.